# Combining and optimizing python 3 list comprehension

Tags: python, optimization, list-comprehension, python-3.8

So I am using structs to create lists of vertices and normals as read from a data file. The following code *does* work as I need it to. Previously this was written as nested for loops, which also worked. 
My question is: Which is the most optimal? Is there a way to combine these two list comprehensions into one? And would that be a good idea or not?

```
vs = struct.Struct('fff')
verts = [vs.unpack_from(data, 50*facet + 12*i + 12) for facet in range(facets) for i in range(3)]
vnorms = [vs.unpack_from(data, 50*facet) for facet in range(facets)]
```

Comment: List comprehensions are often more efficient than loops, since every step in a loop needs to be interpreted. OTOH, they can quickly become unreadable. You need to decide where the optimum tradeoff is, for your purposes.

Comment: In addition to @TomZych, you could use newlines within a list comprehension which kind of makes them more readable.

Comment: @TomZych every step in a list comprehension needs to be interpreted too. It is essentially a for-loop under the hood. Generally, list comprehensions are *slightly* faster than the equivalent for-loop, because they cache the `list.append` method resolution. Of course, you can always do something like `append = my_list.append` and use that in a loop, and most of the gains will disappear. Consequently, as the work you do on each iteration becomes greater, the minor speed advantage diminishes and effectively disappears. The main advantage of list comprehensions is readability.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Really! I thought they were more optimized, more compiled code.

Comment: @jan Oh, certainly. I do that for any nontrivial list comprehension. But they can still get pretty hairy.

Comment: @TomZych you can use the `dis` dissasembler to look at the bytecode and compare the bytecode to an equivalent loop.

Comment: Personally: 1) I prefer to use generator expressions instead of list comprehensions in most places 2) I prefer to avoid generator expressions or list comprehensions that have more than one for 3) I like to put the result, for and if on separate lines, even if they aren't so length that they "need it"; I often find this reads more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

The difference in optimization is so small that it does not matter whether or not you can combine the two. In fact, in Python, I would argue that style and readability are more important then efficiency. I do not know how structs work so I can not tell you how you would combine the two.